# PHP simple HTML DOM parser for GG site

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl

I recently started using "php simple html dom parser", but [webSite](http://goodgame.ru) every time return $html->find('something') is empty array.

**Code example:**

```
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$data = file_get_html('http://goodgame.ru/');

$dt = $data->find("li[id=m6] a");
    foreach($dt as $element){
    echo $element->innertext;
}
```

I tried to use curl method get html, but the result was the same

**curl example code:**

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://goodgame.ru/');  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

$data= str_get_html($str); 

$dt = $data->find("li[id=m6] a");

foreach($dt as $element){
    echo $element->innertext;
}
```

Maybe you have any idea?)

Comment: The attributes `id` and `class` have special meaning in css selectors. Did you try `li#m6 a`?

Comment: $data->find("li[id=m6]") return empty array
and $data->find("li") return the same...

Comment: That page (http://goodgame.ru/) only contains JS code which doing redirect. You have to parse this code manually and reproduce that redirect